# How to combine two queries?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I need to combine the two following queries...

```
SELECT     Products.ProductId, Products.ProductDescription, SUM(Inventory.QuantityOutstanding) AS Inventory, Products.AverageCost AS Cost

FROM         Products INNER JOIN
                  Inventory ON Products.Product = Inventory.Product
WHERE    (Inventory > 0) AND (Products.ProductId LIKE 'CAS%') OR
                  (Products.ProductId LIKE 'ASY%')
GROUP BY Products.ProductId, Products.ProductDescription, Products.AverageCost
ORDER BY Products.ProductId
```

Which gives a table like...

```
ProductID    ProductDescription    Inventory    Cost
-------------------------------------------------------
   AB            CD                  0???       0
   UV            XY                    5        555
   .             .                     .         .
   .             .                     .         .
   .             .                     .         .
```

And

```
SELECT Components.ProductId, SUM(SalesOrderItems.QuantityOutstanding) AS Schedule

FROM Structures INNER JOIN
Products AS Components ON  Structures.Component = Components.Product INNER JOIN
Products AS Products ON Products.Product = Structures.Product AND 
Structures.StructureVersion = Products.StructureVersion LEFT OUTER JOIN
SalesOrders INNER JOIN
SalesOrderItems ON SalesOrders.SalesOrder = SalesOrderItems.SalesOrder ON 
Products.Product = SalesOrderItems.Product


WHERE      ((Components.ProductId LIKE 'CAS%') OR (Components.ProductId LIKE 'ASY%')) AND (SalesOrderItems.DueDate < DATEADD(m, 3, GETDATE())) AND (SalesOrderItems.QuantityOutstanding > 0)
GROUP BY Components.ProductId, Products.ProductId
ORDER BY Components.ProductId
```

Which gives a table like...

```
ProductId      Schedule
-------------------------
  AB             360
  UV             3
   .             .
   .             .
   .             .
```

I basically want to have a table that displays the ProductId, (Inventory - Schedule) AS XSStock, and Cost like this...

```
ProductId    XSStock (>0 only)    Cost
-------------------------------------------
   UV             2                222
   .              .                 .
   .              .                 .
   .              .                 .
```

I thought this may be UNION or a subquery but I can't seem to make either work?

I have only begun to use SQL recently so if you could explain your response that would be great!

***KATIA EDIT QUERY:***

```
SELECT ProductId, ProductDescription, Inventory, Cost, SUM(Orders) AS Demand, (Inventory - SUM(Orders)) AS XSStock

FROM (SELECT X.ProductId, X.ProductDescription, X.Inventory, X.Cost, SUM(Y.Schedule) AS Orders

    FROM (SELECT     Products.ProductId, Products.ProductDescription, SUM(Inventory.QuantityOutstanding) AS Inventory, Products.AverageCost AS Cost

        FROM         Products INNER JOIN
                            Inventory ON Products.Product = Inventory.Product
        WHERE     (Products.ProductId LIKE 'CAS%') OR
                            (Products.ProductId LIKE 'ASY%')
        GROUP BY Products.ProductId, Products.ProductDescription, Products.AverageCost) AS X, 

    (SELECT Components.ProductId, SUM(SalesOrderItems.QuantityOutstanding) AS Schedule

        FROM Structures INNER JOIN
        Products AS Components ON  Structures.Component = Components.Product INNER JOIN
        Products AS Products ON Products.Product = Structures.Product AND 
        Structures.StructureVersion = Products.StructureVersion LEFT OUTER JOIN
                SalesOrders INNER JOIN
        SalesOrderItems ON SalesOrders.SalesOrder = SalesOrderItems.SalesOrder ON 
        Products.Product = SalesOrderItems.Product

    WHERE      ((Components.ProductId LIKE 'CAS%') OR (Components.ProductId LIKE 'ASY%')) AND (SalesOrderItems.DueDate < DATEADD(m, 3, GETDATE())) AND (SalesOrderItems.QuantityOutstanding > 0)
    GROUP BY Components.ProductId, Products.ProductId) AS Y


WHERE (Y.ProductId LIKE X.ProductId)
GROUP BY X.ProductId, X.ProductDescription, X.Inventory, X.Cost)

WHERE ((Inventory - SUM(Orders)) > 0)
GROUP BY ProductId, ProductDescription, Inventory, Cost

ORDER BY ProductId
```

I am now getting error message...

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'
```

This is in line 30, but I don't know why?

Comment: On a side note... The top query is still displaying results where Inventory = 0, how can i also fix this?

Comment: Give us some sample result for the two original queries, and show us the expected result for the combined query!

Comment: OR
                  (Products.ProductId LIKE 'ASY%') is probably what is causing your query to return a value, even when inventory is 0.

Comment: Assuming that ProductID is the joining value between the two queries, I would create a @TempTable for the result set of each query and then run a joined query on the two temp tables computing Inventory - Schedule

Comment: Meta Mussel - How would I go about creating a @TempTable??

Comment: Please change the order of the join. You need join the structures on products.Product = Products.StructureVersion ... first, and then join to the structures on Components.Product = Structures.Component. It is possible that you used the "Structures" table before you join it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can try to aliasing both query and Selecting them in the select query

```
SELECT x.a, y.b FROM (SELECT * from a) as x, (SELECT * FROM b) as y
```

Comment: Thanks Katia! I have managed to get it working using this method :)

Comment: Sorry to be a pain Katia but are you able to help one last time on my updated question? It is so close to working but I don't know where the syntax error is now!

Comment: You cannot do two where clauses on one query, make and instead of second where. And also only one group by, combine them

Comment: Thanks again Katia! I managed to get it working by renaming the final SELECT AS Z in a similar fashion you showed me

Answer (score 0):

To fix  `Inventory = 0` you just need to add brackets here:

```
`(Inventory > 0) AND *((Products.ProductId LIKE 'CAS%') OR (Products.ProductId LIKE 'ASY%'))`
```

About query: why don't you want to make selection from Products and join everything there? You have ProductsId in all tables. I tried to combine it into one, maybe it will help you:

```
SELECT     Products.ProductId, Products.ProductDescription, SUM(Inventory.QuantityOutstanding) AS Inventory, Products.AverageCost AS Cost
 SUM(SalesOrderItems.QuantityOutstanding) AS Schedule
from Products

inner join Inventory ON Products.Product = Inventory.Product
inner join structures AS Components ON  Structures.Component = Products.Product INNER JOIN
inner join structurs as structures.Product = Product.Product and
Structures.StructureVersion = Products.StructureVersion 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
SalesOrders INNER JOIN SalesOrderItems ON SalesOrders.SalesOrder = SalesOrderItems.SalesOrder ON 
Products.Product = SalesOrderItems.Product
WHERE    (Inventory > 0) AND ((Products.ProductId LIKE 'CAS%') OR (Products.ProductId LIKE 'ASY%'))
and  ((Products.ProductId LIKE 'CAS%') OR (Products.ProductId LIKE 'ASY%')) 
AND (SalesOrderItems.DueDate < DATEADD(m, 3, GETDATE())) AND (SalesOrderItems.QuantityOutstanding > 0)

GROUP BY Products.ProductId, Products.ProductDescription, Products.AverageCost
ORDER BY Products.ProductId
```

Comment: I tried it and please see my updated question as I ran out of characters here in the comment section lol

Comment: That was my mistake, you need: Component.Component = Products.Product

Comment: This doesn't seem to work? The query now runs with no error message but the table produced is blank. When I remove some of the constraints it shows results but not desired results?

Comment: When you are joining tables by ProductId - it will find corresponding Schedule and Inventory with the same ProductId. But if in at least one of these table there will be no such product id - it won't be in your result. In this case you can try to use outter join.